# Favourite way to sort / filter tables in Laravel on client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have various tables that contain MySQL data in my Laravel web app, but I want the user to be able to sort on the fly by any column header they want; same with filtering. To be clear, I want this all to be processed on the client side.

From what I can tell, Laravel doesn't ship with this functionality. In the past I was able to do this with DataTables, but that was with a pure php application; not with a big framework such as Laravel.

What are some of your favourite solutions?

Comment: Laravel is a PHP framework. It only does server side things. You will have to use javascript (e.g. DataTables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@lukasgeiter is correct in saying that this is more of a javascript question and has nothing much to do with laravel.

That said, I've found the most simplest way to achieve something like this is Sortable. You can find out more here: http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/

If you set it up properly, all you have to do is add class='sortable', to your  element and it would *just work*.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's very easy. Thanks for the share. I also found this great guide for [using DataTables with Laravel](http://barnaszalai.eu/article/tips-and-tricks-using-datatables-with-laravel)